# setSizePolicy(self, QSizePolicy): argument 1 has unexpected type 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QSizePolicy'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyside2

*UI* код сделан в *QT designer 5.14.1*.
Не понимаю в чём проблема.

```
from PySide2.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint,
    QRect, QSize, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide2.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor, QFont,
    QFontDatabase, QIcon, QLinearGradient, QPalette, QPainter, QPixmap,
    QRadialGradient)
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1184, 539)
        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(27, 27, 27);")
        MainWindow.setTabShape(QTabWidget.Rounded)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.Clear = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Clear.setObjectName(u"Clear")
        self.Clear.setGeometry(QRect(10, 190, 131, 61))
```

При запуске выдаёт ошибку:

```
  File "D:/Python Projects/Calculator/main.py", line 15, in <module>
    window = MainWindow()
  File "D:/Python Projects/Calculator/main.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.setupUi(self)
  File "D:\Python Projects\Calculator\ui_EngCalc.py", line 28, in setupUi
    MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  setSizePolicy(self, QSizePolicy): argument 1 has unexpected type 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QSizePolicy'
  setSizePolicy(self, QSizePolicy.Policy, QSizePolicy.Policy): argument 1 has unexpected type 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QSizePolicy'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Код запускаемого файла.

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from ui_EngCalc import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю что проблема в том, что вы используете и *PySide2* и *PyQt5*.

Пусть модуль, который вы создали в  Qt Designer, называется **ui_EngCalc.ui**

Выполните:

```
pyuic5 ui_EngCalc.ui -o ui_EngCalc.py -x
```

и запустите **main.py**

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

from ui_EngCalc import Ui_MainWindow

       
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```